# Compare current route to array of allowed routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, compare, laravel-routing

I'm not sure the best way to go about doing this, so comparing current to an array is just where my mind is currently at.

I'd like to have a group of routes execute a filter and then based on the route a different outcome from that filter. Something along the lines of

```
if(in_array($currentRoute, $allowedRoutes){
    do action1
}
else{
    do action2
}
```

I have a number of different possibilities as far as uri's are concered

```
Route::get('/content','ContentController@index')
Route::post('/dynamic/{dynamic}','DynamicController@store')
Route::delete('dynamic/{dynamic}/content/{content}','ContentController@destroy')
```

All of the above may have query strings and all have a number of HTTP methods. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign aliases to each route, so that you can identify the current route name despite the query strings. For example:

```
Route::get('/content', array('uses'=>'ContentController@index', 'as'=>'content'))
Route::post('/dynamic/{dynamic}', array('uses'=>'DynamicController@store', 'as'=>'dynamic.show'))
Route::delete('dynamic/{dynamic}/content/{content}', array('uses'=>'ContentController@destroy', 'as'=>'dynamic.destroy'))
```

Now in a filter, you can do the following:

```
$allowedRoutes = array('content');
$currentRoute = Route::currentRouteName();

if (in_array($currentRoute, $allowedRoutes)) {
    // do action1
} else {
    // do action2
}
```

Note that this filter needs to be an `after` filter, not a `before` filter.